# Noty modal not closing on n.close()

Tags: javascript, jquery, noty

The idea is to check if a certain page is available every second. When the page is available, I want to show a Noty-modal where user can choose to reload the current page or to close the modal. I use Noty.js  v3.1.4.

JS Code

```html
<script>
    var n = new Noty({
        text: "Website under construction",
        type: 'alert',
        layout: 'center',
        theme: 'bootstrap-v4',
        modal: 'true',
        buttons: [
            Noty.button("Yes", "btn btn-primary", function () {
                location.reload();
            }),
            Noty.button("No", "btn btn-primary ml-3", function () {
                checkAvailability = true;
                n.close();
            })],
        animation: {
            open: 'animated fadeIn faster',
            close: 'animated fadeOut faster'
        }
    });
    var checkAvailability = true;
    var timeout = 1000;
    
    (function(){
        if (checkAvailability) {    
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://example.com",
                type : 'HEAD',
                success : function(){
                    //website is available
                    checkAvailability = false;
                    timeout = 30000; // set timeout to 30 seconds, no need to check every second anymore
                    n.show();
                },
                error: function (){
                    //website is not available
                    checkAvailability = true;
                    timeout = 1000;
                }
            });
        }
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, timeout);
    })();
</script>
```

The AJAX request works and at a certain moment the Noty Modal shows up. Now when I click on 'No', the modal won't close. I see that `n.closed` changes from **`false`** to **`true`**, but the modal doesn't disappear. There is no log in the console. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe the button classes need to be exclusive, both of your buttons contain `btn btn-primary`. Make them distinct like in the [example](https://ned.im/noty/#/confirm).

Comment: Tested it, but that doesn't make the difference.  The state of the Noty `n.closed` is changed, so there is some trigger. But the modal doesn't disappear.

Comment: You are right. Doesn't work, I tried and saved this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgroe4Lh/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem . It turned out to be "animate.css" package version that causing the n.close() not work.  Because it close when anmation end, and animate.css wrong version can make animation not work, so Noty cannot close.